# Determining Whether a Point is a local Minimizer of Scalar Function

Tags: derivatives, optimization

> Given $p(x) = \frac{3}{8}x^4 + x^3 +\frac{3}{4}x^2 - \frac{9}{8}$, determine whether $x = -1$ is a local minimizer of $p$.

We have $p'(-1) = p''(-1) = 0$. So the point is a critical point but the second derivative test is inconclusive. Is there another approach one could take which doesen't involve use of mathematical software?

Comment: Do a sign analysis of the first derivative around $-1$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know the first two derivatives vanish at a point, then the original function (mod some constant) has a root of multiplicity at least $3$ at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $p(-1) = -1$ consider the following separation:

$$p(x) = \left(\frac{3}{8}x^4 + x^3 + \frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{8}\right) -1$$

$-1$ is a root of the polynomial in the parentheses. Given that the first two derivatives of that polynomial vanish at $-1$ but not the third (since this polynomial and $p$ share the same derivatives), we know that the root has exactly multiplicity $3$.

A root with an odd multiplicity can be neither a local min or max, and this is not changed by a vertical translation.

Comment: So if the first $n$ derivatives only of a polynomial are zero at a point (root), then the root has multiplicity $n+1$? I guess $p(x)$ can also be factored as some term multiplied by $(x-1)^3 $ then.

Comment: Also any intuition for why a root with odd multiplicity cant be a local min or max?

Comment: @Pame only even multiplicities bounce at their roots.

Comment: @Pame and no, $p(x) + 1$ can be factored as $(x-1)^3$ times a linear polynomial.